# Identifying the origin of byte arrays in a reactive chain in Project Reactor

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

I am constructing a color image from 3 grayscale images.  I make 3 separate (parallel) requests for each color band using rsocket, which returns a `Mono<byte[]>`.  I need to collect all 3 byte arrays as a list so that I can build the the image properly.  However, I'm confused as to how I am able to identify which band the byte array belonged to in the next reactive operation.

Here is some sample code:

```
 return Flux.just(redRequest, blueRequest, greenRequest)
                .parallel()
                .flatMap(client::getBytes) // calls the remote service to get the bytes for the given color band
                .sequential()
                .collectList()
                .map(response -> {
                   byte[] redBytes = response.get(0); //???
                }
```

I created a wrapper class to hold the original request, byte array, and band identifier so I could pass all the objects around in each operation, but because the response from my rsocket client is a Mono, I can only materialize (probably wrong terminology) the byte array by calling it in a map or flatMap, at which point I don't have access to my wrapper class and I'm not sure which band the byte array belongs to.

Can I fix this by simply not calling the client in a parallel request?  Would I ever be guaranteed that items will propagate through the chain in the order I defined them in the `Flux.just()`.

Basically in the last map, I just really want to be able to know which byte array belongs to which color band.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap each request in the object with a color field and change the `flatMap` piece of your pipeline that sends these requests:

```
Flux.just(
  new Request(redRequest, RED),
  new Request(blueRequest, BLUE),
  new Request(greenRequest, GREEN)
)
.parallel()
.flatMap(request -> 
  client.getBytes(request)
    .map(response -> new Response(response.get(0), request.color))
)
.sequential()
.collectList()
.map(response -> {
  byte[] redBytes = response.bytes;
  Color color = response.color;
  // 
})
```

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution.  I had in fact already created a wrapper class as part of my solution, but simply calling the map operation on the response from the client method to access the bytes and set them on the wrapper was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!